# android studio FirebaseRecyclerAdapter

Tags: java, android, firebase

This is the code and this is the error message and i don't know what i do
so what can you do for it 
so what is the error means i don't know.
That all i know and i dont know what should i do for this kind of problem so if it possible to fix it or someone know how can i run it correctly so go a head.

The error shown in image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJl7o.png

And this is the menuviewholder:

```
    public class MenuViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        public TextView txtMenuName;
        public ImageView imageView;


        private ItemClickListener itemClickListener;

        public MenuViewHolder(View itemView){
            super(itemView);
            txtMenuName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.menu_name);
            imageView = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.menu_image);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        public void setItemClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
            this.itemClickListener = itemClickListener;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            itemClickListener.onClick(view,getAdapterPosition(),false);
        }
    }
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6hEF.png

Here is the load part of it and the firbaserec:

```
   Load menu
    recycler_menu =(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler_menu);
    recycler_menu.setHasFixedSize(true);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recycler_menu.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    loadMenu();
}
private void loadMenu()
{
    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Category, MenuViewHolder>
            adapter =new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter <Category, MenuViewHolder>(Category.class,menu_item,MenuViewHolder.class,categorys) {
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MenuViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Category model) {
            holder.txtMenuName.setText(model.getName());
            Picasso.get().load(model.getImage()).into(holder.imageView);
            final Category clickItem = model;
            holder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View viw, int position, boolean isLongClick) {
                    Toast.makeText(Home.this, ""+clickItem.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public MenuViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
            return null;
        }
    };
    recycler_menu.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: Hey @nanoerro, Do mark the answer as correct by clicking the V or tick mark type looking button, next to the answer, as this helps the stack overflow readers and I'd appreciate that too. Cheers! :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the latest version (3.x) of FirebaseUI implements a different method of initializing a FirebaseRecyclerAdapter than previous versions.

Read this for more clarification about this [FirebaseUI docs.](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/database#using-the-firebaserecycleradapter)

From the docs, you can understand everything, but in brief:

First, configure the adapter by building FirebaseRecyclerOptions. I have used the same example from the docs.

```java
FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Chat> options =
                    new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Chat>()
                            .setQuery(query, Chat.class)
                            .build();
```

Next create the `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` object. You should already have a `ViewHolder` subclass for displaying each item. You should be able to do it now.